# If you can't vote your own post, why the arrow icons?

Tags: discussion, voting, design

Why put efforts in showing these messages, instead of just hiding the arrows?

[image]

Comment: There's a general UI principle that applies here. You hide things that the user can't do because of permissions, so he doesn't even know the operation exists, but you show everything he can do, and disable the ones he can't currently do because of state, so you're not confusing him by constantly changing what he can see.

Comment: One could show a tooltip already when hovering over it, not just after clicking. That would shorten the inevitable display of a message a bit. So instead of "this is useful..." show "you can't vote for your own post".

Comment: See also http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/53986/42842

Comment: Could you please give me a link to the question where you took this screen shot? I, the correct case (and spaces) knight, have to carry out my duty.

Comment: @Tril No good for touch screens.

Comment: You could show greyed-out, unclickable arrows. When you hover over them, you get the "can't vote for your own post" tooltip.

Comment: The current system is like a "Close" button in a dialog that says "You cannot close this dialog" on clicking. Showing a choice *disabled* is to indicate the choice *can* be valid, under the right circumstances. And the tooltip can tell why.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It is an aspect of the voting system that self-documents. When you click on an arrow, you get an explanation. If it was hidden and you were wondering "Why are there no arrows on my post, maybe there's something wrong with the system and that's why it has 0 score..." there would be no answer for you.

Quoting [Sam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15623/259867):

> There is a school of thought in the software design and UI space that says something to the effect that:
>
> "You should never hide functionality from a user, regardless of whether they have access to it or not. Instead it is more meaningful to provide the button and display a helpful error message when it is clicked. That way they know it is there and understand the context of the buttons usage better."

Also, see [Remove vote UI elements beside own question and answer posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12599/259867) with [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Comment: The same principle is not used for historically-locked questions and their answers. It is, however, in use on posts locked for *other* reasons.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi What do you expect? Consistency? Ha!

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi that may be to avoid excessive server requests associated with people voting on those very popular questions — the error message that comes up when you vote on your own post or a locked one is generated server-side.

Comment: It would be better if the buttons are disabled and accompanied by the tooltip "You can't vote for your own post" when someone hovers over the disabled buttons. IMHO, this UI design would be a better solution than what SO currently has.

Comment: @ChuongPham Touch devices have no hover, so you still need to have a popover for those.

Comment: @tobiv: Well, that's why W3C standard, Java technologies, etc has different tags, directives, layouts, components, etc so a company can use it to design a version for the desktop, mobile, or for any other environment. Design one version to suit all platforms is IMHO is a backward step in UI design methodology and thinking.