# Should self-vote buttons be disabled?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was wondering if it's difficult/possible for Stack Overflow to disable the vote button for one's own posts?

It is not really a big problem. But quite often I was trying to look at the number of votes for one of my own posts but accidentally hit one of the vote buttons, e.g. on a mobile phone,

[image: buttons]

and get the prompt:

> You can't vote for your own post

Could these button be disabled for my own posts?

There is a related question as pointed out in the comments [If you can't vote your own post, why the arrow icons?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277999/if-you-cant-vote-your-own-post-why-the-arrow-icons).

This is ***not a duplicate*** of the said post, because that question asks about **hiding** the vote buttons. The answers therein said **hiding** isn't a good idea because it changes interface. Here, I am asking about **disabling** the button, which is clearly different. Buttons have been **disabled** elsewhere e.g. in review queues without causing problems.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277999/3933332

Comment: If you disable them, do you want them grayed out, or do you want them to look like regular buttons but ignore all input? How is graying out any different from hiding them, and how is the UX of simply ignoring any user input any better than prompting with an error message?

Comment: @BoltClock If you see the other question/answers about the issues of confusion with hiding (but not with disabling) buttons, you will see the difference.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the said post because that question asks about **hiding** the vote buttons. The answers therein said **hiding** isn't a good idea because it changes interface. Here, I am asking about **disabling** the button, which is clearly different. Buttons have been **disabled** elsewhere e.g. in review queues without causing problems.

Comment: This is such an extremely rare occurrence that I don't think it's worth spending resources on changing. The current behaviour is super clear (it tells you why you can't do what you want to do)

Comment: @Pekka웃 I agree. On small screen devices, this happens a lot though when you check the vote numbers, and you got the message by accident when you were not trying to vote.

Comment: Right, that's true, fair enough

Comment: There's a benefit to this behavior: once you have the vote separation visible, you just vote it away.